# Clicking checkbox using capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

Currently I have a checkbox wrapped by a label.

```
<label for="exercise_form_division_ids_34">
       <input class="check_boxes optional division-checkboxes" type="checkbox" value="34" name="form[division_ids][]" id="exercise_form_division_ids_34"> Technology
</label>
```

In my integration test I tried to use

```
within '.organizations' do
  find("label[for='exercise_form_division_ids_34").click
end

OR

check "exercise_form_division_ids_#{department.id}", allow_label_click: true
```

But I still get this nable to find visible checkbox "calltree_exercise_form_division_ids_2" that is not disabled
`Unable to find visible checkbox "exercise_form_division_ids_" that is not disabled`

Comment: Can you try this - `find(:css, "#exercise_form_division_ids_34).set(true)`

Answer (score 4):

With the limited info provided you have a few potential possibilities.

1. The label/checkbox aren't actually inside an element with the class of the `organizations` on the page.
2. The error `Unable to find visible checkbox "exercise_form_division_ids_" that is not disabled` shows that no id is actually getting inserted into your selector which would tend to indicate that `department` isn't actually persisted in your test.
3. You may be assuming `34` is the correct id based on what it is in your dev environment but that may not be what it is in your test environment.

To narrow down the possibilities the first thing to do would be to grab a screenshot in your with test with `page.save_and_open_screenshot` (assuming you're using a driver which supports screenshots) and make sure there is actually a visible checkbox on the page. If not, you're probably not creating the required objects in the DB prior to your test starting.

Secondly look at the page in your browser and make sure the elements visible on the screen are actually the checkbox and/or the label. If both label & checkbox are being hidden and replaced with some JS widget then you'd need to interact with whatever elements the widget creates in the page (just like a user would). If only the checkbox is being hidden via JS/CSS but the label is visible then

```
check('Technology', allow_label_click: true) # check matching on label text
```

should work.